# Installing HP DeskJet 3520 in CUPS

Tags: debian, printing, cups

I am trying to install this printer into CUPS under Debian 6.

The printer is automatically detected correctly and then I have a list of drivers to choose from.
There is no driver for the 3520 - so I have tried the DeskJet 3500 hpcups and 3500 hpijs drivers.

I have also tried installing the hplip drivers from here: http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/downloads.html

But that seemed to give me no more options when choosing a driver in cups.

The printer adds fine and printing a test page appears to work fine, but there is no output from the printer!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the driver wasnt installed properly.
An automatic install instead of the manual install I had done before fixed the issue and the driver appeared in CUPS to choose.